# Not null constraint violation when flushing unidirectional entities

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

I am playing a little bit with unidirectional and bidirectional mappings using `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations, but I cannot break the wall through for unidirectional one when persisting entities and flushing them into the database.

So, two tables `delivery_company` might have many `delivery`:

SQL (Oracle):

```
CREATE TABLE delivery (
    delivery_id          NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
    price                NUMBER(5, 2) NOT NULL,
    delivery_time        DATE NOT NULL,
    delivery_company_id  NUMBER(2) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE delivery ADD CONSTRAINT delivery_pk PRIMARY KEY ( delivery_id );

CREATE TABLE delivery_company (
    delivery_company_id    NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    delivery_company_name  VARCHAR2(15 CHAR) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE delivery_company ADD CONSTRAINT delivery_company_pk PRIMARY KEY ( delivery_company_id );

ALTER TABLE delivery
    ADD CONSTRAINT delivery_delivery_company_fk FOREIGN KEY ( delivery_company_id )
        REFERENCES delivery_company ( delivery_company_id );
```

Unidirectional mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Delivery")
class DeliveryUniDirectional
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "delivery_id_sequence", sequenceName = "delivery_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "delivery_id_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "delivery_id")
    public Long deliveryId;

    public BigDecimal price;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date deliveryTime;

// setters, getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "delivery_company")
class DeliveryCompanyUniDirectional {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "delivery_company_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "delivery_company_id_sequence", sequenceName = "delivery_company_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "delivery_company_id_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long deliveryCompanyId;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String deliveryCompanyName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "delivery_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<DeliveryUniDirectional> deliveries = new LinkedList<>();

// setters getters
}
```

When I run `@DataJpaTest` test:

```
    @Test
    public void insertDeliveryUniDirectional()
    {
        DeliveryCompanyUniDirectional deliveryCompany = new DeliveryCompanyUniDirectional();
        deliveryCompany.setDeliveryCompanyName("aa");

        DeliveryUniDirectional delivery = new DeliveryUniDirectional();
        delivery.setPrice(BigDecimal.ONE);
        delivery.setDeliveryTime(new Date());

        deliveryCompany.getDeliveries().add(delivery);

        entityManager.persist(deliveryCompany);
        entityManager.flush();
    }
```

I receive

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch ...
// 
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TESTUSER"."DELIVERY"."DELIVERY_COMPANY_ID")
```

when `entityManager.flush();`.

I tried in `DeliveryCompanyUniDirectional` to use `@JoinColumn` without insertable and updatable, but in that case hibernate complains:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource ...
// ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: wieczorek.jakub.shop.business.spring.model.domain.DeliveryUniDirectional column: delivery_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Definitely there is a problem with `NOT NULL` constraint for the foreign key in `delivery` table. When I try it with bidirectional mapping, persisting and flushing work very good, but I would like to achieve the same using unidirectional.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your @JoinColumn should be `delivery_company_id` since it's your foreign key

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="delivery_company_id", referencedColumnName="delivery_company_id", nullable = false)
private List<DeliveryUniDirectional> deliveries = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: I was getting ready to disagree with Eklavya, there, because delivery_company_id is a column in the table that you're inside, at that point.  But that is because I skimmed and realized you didn't follow what I consider to be a convention:  That the id column in any table is just named id, and only foreign keys are named <tablename>_id.  When you're making a OneToMany annotation, the JoinColumn is always the column in the other table that points back to me.

Comment: @Zag see the table creation sql in post, update to more clear

Comment: Thanks @Eklayva for working solution (I just had to add ```nullable = false```, because of not null constraint). Thanks @Zag for a useful comment.